# Trying to make multiple input Search in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

Am trying to make a `laravel search` which has 4 columns. What am trying to do is, if the user search using one input field they will get the related result and if the user use multiple search input fields they will get the related result.

Here's my form:

```
<form action="{{ route('properties-list') }}" method="POST" role="search">
   @csrf
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <input style="height: 48px;" id="title" name="title" type="text" class="input-text form-control"
               placeholder="Search by Title">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="type">
               <option value=""> Category </option>
               <option value="Apartments"> Apartments </option>
               <option value="Houses"> Houses </option>
               <option value="Commercial"> Commercial </option>
               <option value="Garages"> Garages </option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <input style="height: 48px;" id="datepicker" name="created_at" type="text"
               class="input-text form-control" placeholder="Date of Posting" autocomplete="false">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <input style="height: 48px;" id="search_term" name="location" type="text" class="input-text form-control" placeholder="Search City,Area">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row p-3">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-12">
         <div class="form-group">
            <button class="search-button">Search</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here's my Controller:

```
public function homeSearch(Request $request)
{
    $title = $request->title;
    $type = $request->type;
    $created_at = $request->created_at;
    $location = $request->location;

if (empty($title) && empty($type) && empty($created_at) && empty($location)) {
    Session::flash('danger', "You didn't select any search any search.");
    return redirect()->back();
}

$properties = Property::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $title . '%')
    ->orWhere('type', $type)
    ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%')
    ->orWhere('created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $created_at . '%')
    ->get();
dd($properties);
```

}

From the following logic if I used to search title "Note":
I have already saved the following title's in my DB

> Want to buy a Note 10 plus
>
> Iphone for sale
>
> I want to sale my note 4

I'm getting all the 3 objects in my dd($properties) if I used 'where' instead of 'orWhere' sometimes it gives me my desire result and sometimes it returns an empty object.

Here's the reference search:
https://yts.mx/browse-movies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use when clause

see: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-when

```
$properties = Property::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . request()->title . '%')
                        ->when(request()->type, function($query) {
                            $query->where('type', request()->type)
                        })
                        ->when(request()->location, function($query) {
                            $query->where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . request()->location . '%')
                        })
                        ->when(request()->created_at, function($query) {
                            $query->where('created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . request()->created_at . '%')
                        })->get();
```

Comment: Great! just added the "get()" function at the end of the logic and I got my desire result.
Thank you so much ^_^